# How do I compare data from excel spreadsheet to tables in oracle and how do I enter the results into excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I want to compare `user_id` from an excel spreadsheet to three tables and copy the `user_id` that are the same to a spreadsheet

```sql
select user_id, userName, Dept
  from 
  myExcelel sheet (user_tab), a.Table_a, b.Table_B,c. Table_C
Where user_id = a.user_ID
and
user_ID = b.user_id
and 
User_id = c.user_id
Group by Dept;
```

Comment: Welcome! But what is the problem you're facing? Can you provide some logs, output, and/or describe it?

Comment: Hello! Please take a look at `LOAD DATA INFILE` in SQL!

Comment: You may use sqldeveloper tool. in the toll you can use a wizard to import or export excel from a table or a query result.